# Angular CLI Dropdown-bootstrap

Tags: html, dropdown, angular-bootstrap, angular-cli

### Versions:

`//package.json:
"devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "1.8.10",
    "typings": "1.3.1"
  }`

### Problem

I'm changing an already existing frontend from angular 2 to angular-cli. All the routing and most of the functions are implemented now, but I fail since a long time to implement a dropdown-Menu which workes just fin in pure angular 2:

**HTML:**
[image]

**- Result old pure angular2-app**

[image]

Logout opens when I click on Users)

**- Result new Angular cli**

I click on User and the frontend tries to route me to localhost/# (which I redirected to my default component).

**Remarks**

I added the old css-Files to the new Project, so that should be updated (nav navbar etc.. are all defined)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

### Solution

In the End I used ng2-dropdown

install ng2-dropdown

`npm install ng2-dropdown --save-dev`

open src/System-conf

insert:

```js
const map: any = {
  'jquery': 'vendor/jquery',
  'bootstrap': 'vendor/bootstrap',
  "ng2-dropdown": "vendor/ng2-dropdown"
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  "ng2-dropdown": { "main": "index.js", "defaultExtension": "js" }
};
```

As you see we still need bootstrap and of course jquery (also install with npm)

open angualr-cli-build.js (in ./)

Enter:

```js
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
     [. . .],
      'ng2-dropdown/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
};
```

This will copy paste the code in our dist-Directory

And use it in the html-File as shown below (dont forget to import and use the dropdown_directives in the component)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--NEW--vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
import {DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES} from "ng2-dropdown";
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--NEW--vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
  directives: [DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES]
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" dropdown>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" dropdown-open>My Heroes</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Badman</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sadman</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lieman</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I hope I can help other developers!

### EDIT

Codesnipets don't work they need to be in a ng-cli or ng Project!

### /EDIT